# Comparar strings desordenado

Tags: java, string

RESUELTO. Necesito programar un método que compare dos strings y me devuelva true si son iguales, considerando iguales a los strings que tienen los mismos carácteres en el mismo orden aunque estén en diferente índice. Pongo un ejemplo para que se entienda mejor, "ASRAT" sería igual a "RATAS" o a "SRATA" ya que las letras siguen la misma secuencia a pesar de tener posiciones diferentes en cada string.

Al final lo he conseguido, dejo por aquí la solución por si alguien la necesita en un futuro. Basicamente compruebo que no sean null y después concatenando dos veces el primer String se puede usar el mètodo contains() para saber si el segundo String se encuentra en esa secuencia.

```
public boolean equalsADN(String adn1, String adn2) {
    // Compare two ADN  
    if (adn1 == null || adn2 == null) {
        return false;
    }else {
        return (adn1.length() == adn2.length() && (adn1+adn1).contains(adn2));
    }
}
```

Un saludo y muchas gracias!

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. 
Las preguntas del tipo "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas, ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato del sitio.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: Recuerda que puedes editar tu pregunta cuantas veces sea necesario y añadir la info relevante (en los comentarios no se ve bien el código y abajo sólo van nuestros intentos de respuesta). La opción editar está justo bajo la pregunta y las etiquetas!

Comment: Empieza usando los métodos length() y charAt(index) de la clase String para obtener la lista de caracteres. Lo siguiente sería ordenar esa lista alfabéticamente. Finalmente, haz esas operaciones de conversión a listas de caracteres ordenados con todos los Strings y compara.

Comment: La solucion que propones no siempre funciona, puedes probar con ATRAS y RATAS y veras que no obtendras el resultado deseado

Comment: Hola Japv, gracias por el  comentario. En el caso que planteas el metodo debe devolver false, ya que ATRAS y RATAS sí tienen los mismos carácteres pero no los tienen en el mismo orden.